# Joint PMF in class of n students problem

Tags: probability, self-study, joint-distribution

Problem in my book:

> A class of n students takes a test consisting of m questions. Suppose that student i submitted answers to the first m(i) questions.

> a) The grader randomly picks one answer, call it (I,J), where I is the student ID number (taking values 1,...,n) and J is the question number (taking values 1,...,m). Assume that all answers are equally likely to be picked. Calculate the joint and marginal PMFs of I and J."

The solution begins,

> Since all possible values of (I,J) are equally likely, ...

Since the students all start with the first question and then answer some random number of questions, it seems like the first question will be answered more than the other questions on average. In other words, lower values of J (i.e. the first questions) are more likely to be answered than higher values of J (i.e., the last questions).

I'm assuming that "all answers are equally likely to be picked" means that once a student is identified, whatever answers he/she answered would be the list from which any of those questions will be equally likely to be picked.

An example: suppose student #1 answered questions #1-4, student #2 answered questions #1-8, Student #3 answered questions #1-10. In this case, question #1 will be answered 3 times and question #10 will only be answered once. (In this case, if student #1 is picked, then any of the 4 questions student #1 answered may also be picked. That's what I think "all answers are equally likely to be picked" means, which doesn't change the probability of any one question being answered overall.)

So, the statement that "all possible values of (I,J) are equally likely" seems wrong.

Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).